# Call a VueJS life cycle hook from within a method on the same component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I use VueJS's `mounted` hook in my "container" components to fetch data that builds the view. When that container is destroyed, I use the `beforeDestroy` and `destroyed` life cycle hooks to "clean up" the component.

These three hooks are *not* called when the route has changed to the same route, but with different parameters. The suggested way to handle this is by listening for `$route` changes in `watch` like so:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
    this.id = to.params.id
    this.getPageData()
  }
}
```

However, instead of copying the logic from `mounted`, `beforeDestroy`, and `destroyed`, I was hoping to do something like this:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {

    // Manually run lifecycle clean-up hooks
    this.beforeDestroy()
    this.destroyed()

    // Update Id, and run mounted
    this.id = to.params.id
    this.mounted()
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it looks like the hooks are not exposed on `$vm`. Is there a way to accomplish this that I am not aware of? Am I missing something obvious? Or is there a better / preferred approach?

Comment: You could extract your code inside the hooks into a component method, and then just call that method in both places?

Comment: It looks like I overlooked the obvious, thanks @BrianGlaz. In instances like this, is it better to have you submit an answer that I can accept after a period of time, or to remove the question?

Comment: I will write up a more detailed answer shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could extract your code inside each lifecycle hook into a component method, and then call that method in both places. Here is an example:

```
mounted: function() {
    this.__mounted();
},

methods: {
    __mounted() {
        //mounted code here
    }
},

watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
        this.__mounted();
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to just copy `mounted()` hook somehow?